# Xserve Xeon: 1TB Drive does not show when plugged in

Tags: hard-drive, mac-osx-server, apple, xeon, xserve

I've got an Xserve and when I plug in a 1TB Western Digital Drive, the drive does not show up in the finder. There is nothing wrong with this drive, and I am at a lose as to why this could be, some hints and tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drive needed to have a jumper set on the back to get it to run in PHY mode. The drive defaults to Sata II and the motherboard is SATA I.

Adding the jumper made the difference, and the drive shows in finder now :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you see it in Disk Utility and format it there?

Comment: It doesn't show in disk utility - checked already :)